# how to use jquery to save the text on the page even after refreshing it?

Tags: jquery, local-storage

```
  $(".saveBtn").click(function() {
  value = $(this).siblings("textarea").val();
  hourString = $(this).siblings("div").text();
  localStorage.setItem(hourString, JSON.stringify(value));
```

'''I think I have it saved to local storage, now how to i get it to display'''

Answer (score 1):

You can use LocalStorage like so:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('key', 'content')
```

And read it like so:

```
const val = window.localStorage.getItem('key')
```

In your case you will save it that way:

```
$(".saveBtn").click(function() {    
    const value = $(this).siblings("textarea").val();
    localStorage.setItem('myVal', value);
})
```

So you can display it by the textarea with following

```
const savedVal = localStorage.getItem('myVal')
$(this).siblings("textarea").val(savedVal);
```